# Calculate the following integral: $\iint_D (x^2 + y^2)dxdy$ using Fubini's Theorem

Tags: integration

I am trying to calculate the following integral using Fubini's theorem:
$$\iint_D (x^2 + y^2)dxdy$$
with $D$ is the region limited by $y = \sin{x}$ and the interval $[0, \pi]$. But I am yet to fully understand the concept.

Where do I begin and how do I proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$D=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2: 0\leq x\leq \pi, 0\leq y\leq \sin(x)\}$ is a normal domain, hence
$$ \iint_{D}(x^2+y^2)\,dx\,dy =\underbrace{\iint_{D}x^2\,dx\,dy}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\iint_D y^2\,dx\,dy}_{I_2}$$
where
$$ I_1 = \int_{0}^{\pi}x^2\sin(x)\,dx =\left[(2-x^2)\cos x+2x\sin x\right]_{0}^{\pi}=\pi^2-4$$
and
$$ I_2 = \int_{0}^{1} y^2 (\pi-\arcsin y)\,dy \stackrel{y\mapsto\sin\theta}{=}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(\theta)\sin^2(\theta)(\pi-\theta)\,d\theta=\frac{2}{9}+\frac{\pi}{6}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Note that $\sin(x)\geq 0$ for $x\in[0,\pi]$. Then write the double as an iterated integral
$$\int_{x=0}^{\pi}\left(\int_{y=0}^{\sin(x)}(x^2 + y^2)dy\right) dx.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: I believe so. So when I am given a region of limit, that would basically be one of the intervals>

Comment: Yes... but I warn you that this is not a general rule.